# Drop duplicate where column value of duplicate row is zero

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to drop duplicates where the value of a specific column of the duplicated row is zero.

```
    Name  Division  Clients
0   Dave    Sales   0
1   Dave    Sales   15
2   Karen   Sales   10
3   Rachel  HR      20
4   Dan     HR      45
5   Dan     HR      0
```

The output I'm hoping to achieve is seen below

```
    Name  Division  Clients
1   Dave    Sales   15
2   Karen   Sales   10
3   Rachel  HR      20
4   Dan     HR      45
```

Any assistance anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: so do you mean any row that has zero or any duplicate?

Comment: No, just drop any row that has a duplicate (Name and Division appear twice) but only retaining records where Clients != 0.

Comment: You can try this df= df.drop_duplicates()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a check if Clients == 0 and find all duplicates based on Name and Division, then do an & and inverse, then boolean mask:

```
c = df['Clients'].eq(0)
df[~(df.duplicated(['Name','Division'],keep=False) & c)]
```

---

```
     Name Division  Clients
1    Dave    Sales       15
2   Karen    Sales       10
3  Rachel       HR       20
4     Dan       HR       45
```

Thanks to Seabean , consider the following df:

```
df1 = df.append(pd.DataFrame([['Dave','HR',0]],columns=df.columns),ignore_index=True)

print(df1)
     Name Division  Clients
0    Dave    Sales        0
1    Dave    Sales       15
2   Karen    Sales       10
3  Rachel       HR       20
4     Dan       HR       45
5     Dan       HR        0
6    Dave       HR        0

c = df1['Clients'].eq(0)
print(df1[~(df1.duplicated(['Name','Division'],keep=False) & c)])

     Name Division  Clients
1    Dave    Sales       15
2   Karen    Sales       10
3  Rachel       HR       20
4     Dan       HR       45
6    Dave       HR        0
```

Comment: Is this handling the definition of duplicates as (Name and Division) (not only Name) being the same ?

Comment: I used this solution while adding ```.drop_duplicates(['Name','Division'])``` and it did the job.

Comment: Try add the 7th row with Dave, HR, and 0, then you will see this newly added row which is not a duplicate also got removed.

Comment: Perfect now!  Great!

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how your data is organized... If you're reading in from a csv you could do something like this:

```
#Get the Data:
data = pd.read_csv("employees.csv") 

#Sort by Clients so the zeros are dropped instead of the Clients:
data.sort_values("Clients", inplace = True) 

#Drop any duplicates based on name:
data.drop_duplicates(subset ="Name", 
                     keep = False, inplace = True)
```